# How can I get react to create a project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I installed g-create-react-app on my system it worked fine, then after that I tried creating a react app but it has being giving me this error.

```
adnan@Adnan-Junior MINGW64 ~/React
$ npx create-react-app sure

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\alijan\React\sure.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^0.1.1","markdownli'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alijan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-30T10_00_14_886Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting sure/ from C:\Users\alijan\React
Done.
```

I'm kinda fed up, can someone help me out with this?
or do you need more informations?

Or can someone show me the visual studio code alternative if there's one or does it have to be with git bash?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try `npm cache clean --force` and then try again?